# Not able to sort by date in python

Tags: python, bash

I have a bsh script that has a while loop which a python script to check SSL cert expiry date on a bunch of hosts.
The script executes perfectly and outputs:

domainA--> expiry_date_A
domainB--> expiry_date_B

I need to be able to sort by date so I can know which expire soon.

Here are the scripts:

```
**cat CE.sh**

for dm in `cat dm.txt`; do
    python3 check-cert.py $dm
done

**cat dm.txt**
google.com
ibm.com
cisco.com
example.com

cat check-cert.py
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import sys
import time

def get_SSL_Expiry_Date(host, port):
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, 443))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
    raw_date = x509.get_notAfter()
    decoded_date = raw_date.decode("utf-8")
    dexpires = time.strptime(decoded_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%Sz")
    print (domain, "expires --> ", time.strftime('%m/%d/%y', dexpires))
domain = sys.argv[1]
port = 443
get_SSL_Expiry_Date(domain, port)
```

Here is the output:

```
google.com expires -->  04/23/19
ibm.com expires -->  03/15/20
cisco.com expires -->  12/07/19
example.com expires -->  12/02/20
```

I need the output sorted by date so it should be:

```
google.com expires -->  04/23/19
cisco.com expires -->  12/07/19
ibm.com expires -->  03/15/20
example.com expires -->  12/02/20
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: sort directly according to `dexpires`. But you need to store results not just print them for that.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], and clarify whether you want to implement this in Python or Bash.

Comment: If you use ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD, you get simple sorting for free: that format sorts the same lexically as chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a dataframe of the values

```
pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Name columns

```
output.columns=['Source','Date']
```

Then sort it:

```
output['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(output.Date)
output.sort_values(by='Date')
```

Comment: As per your code `output` is NOT a dataframe. Hope it helps

Comment: That did not work.  Do you mind posting the entire code?